# Solr Exclude Filter for Category

Tags: solr, solr4, solrnet

Using Solr 6, for e-commerce catalog with search and filtering.

I need to exclude all products for certain category? Not sure how to do that in Solr. Can you give some idea, how can we achieve that?

Note that, CategoryID is a multi valued string field, as one product can be assigned to multiple categories.

Comment: What is your schema structure? How are you storing categories ? Tell us a bit more .

Comment: @codechat added details, let me know if you need any other details. Thank you

Comment: No, haven't tried. I don't see this things anywhere in doc? Can you point me to the document where this is discussed, so I can review it in details.

Answer (score 1):

Use the boolean "NOT" operator.

```
* NOT CategoryID:111
```

Alternative syntax :

```
* -CategoryID:111
* !CategoryID:111
```

Documentation : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser#TheStandardQueryParser-BooleanOperatorsSupportedbytheStandardQueryParser